# Do we have any thumb rules to estimate man days for JUnit test cases

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, junit5

We have a project which is 10 years old with more than 10 million lines of java code. Now because of some reasons organization decided to write the JUnit test cases for the old code. We are using Mockito JUnit test cases. As part of this change we have to estimate the man days effort. Its very difficult to estimates on the existing code and moreover I am new to the project. Just want to know is there any thumb rule to estimate based on number of lines of code.

Comment: I think you have an impossible task at hand. Usually code that is not written to be unit-testable, is not unit-testable. Being new to the project, you have no idea what surprises there's ahead. IMO it's also pointless to write unit tests just for the sake of having unit tests. You should write the tests as you make changes to the application, making the application testable part by part. I recommend you to check out a book by Michael Feathers names "Working Efficiently with Legacy Code"

Comment: Yes, agree with you. Plan is to move the project to cloud by January. To move to cloud JUnit code coverage should be more than or equal to 80%. We are using Spring MVC based web application with Controller -> Service -> Dao layers. Now we are writing for each layer separately. This is the reason we are using Mockito. Suppose if we are writing the test case for Controller then we will mock the below layers like Service & DAO. Same with the service layer testing. While testing service layer, we will mock the DAO layer.

Comment: "organization decided" ... "80% coverage" ... " by January" ... -- classic foobar. As @kaskelotti wrote: You cannot just write test cases. Properly a lot of production code has too refactored to be unit testable. But by doing so you increasing the risk of new bugs.

It would make more sense to write integration or end-to-end tests to at least have feedback cycle when you touch production code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cannot give you a realistic estimate but I can give you a lower bound estimate which will - hopefully - show that the task at hand should not be done. For a helpful line coverage of 80+ percent you will need approximately as many lines of hand-crafted test code as you have production code; so that’s 10 mio LOTC. With 20 years experience of TDD I don’t think I’ve ever written more than 500 LOC of code on a single day (actually it’s probably less than 50 line on most days). So the lower bound is 10000000/500 = 20000 days or 100 people doing nothing but writing tests for a full year.

Does that sound ridiculous? Because it is. Getting a system of that size into a state of reasonable quality requires different means. You might want to read up on strategies for dealing with and replacing legacy systems. Getting all (or most) code under test now is not viable.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, the coverage you want to achieve correlates with effort required to write the proper tests in comparison to the effort required to write the code in that way, that the coverage equals the ratio between effort for writing testing and the total development effort.

```
c = t / (t + e)
```

Where

- t is the effort required for developing tests,
- e the effort spent for developing code and
- t + e = total development effort (tests + code)
- c the coverage.

For example:

- for 0% coverage, 0% of your total development effort is required, obviously
- for 20% coverage, 20% of your total development effort is required for writing tests
- for 50% coverage, 50% of your total development effort is required for writing tests
- for 80% coverage, 80% of your total development effort is required for writing tests

I think, you get the picture. 
It's a rule of thumb that might get a bit unprecise in higher values ( -> 100%) and really depends on the experience of the developers for writing testable code and robust tests. It's further based on the assumption & observation that the effort is not linear with the coverage - higher coverages require extra effort for hard-to-test cases and that non-trivial testcode, especially for setup, requires more test-code than tested code.
The advantage of this formula is, that it's simple to understand and calculate with only the relevant metrics (effort, coverage), but it's no scientific method, just a quick way to estimate.

For legacy code (which is probably not too well testable), for which you hopefully know the effort that has already been put into, you can estimate the effort *required* to achieve a target coverage.

So the formula for estimating based on the spent effort and the target coverage is

```
t = e*c / (1-c)
```

So if you've already spent 1000 person-days (PD), you require another 1000 person-days to get to 50% coverage. Or 500 PDs for 33%, or 250 PDs for 20%. Or 4000 PDs for 80%.

Compared to Johannes' Lower-Bound estimation:

- assumption: 500 LoC / PDs -> 10mio LOC = 20.000 PDs
- Johannes Lower-Bound estimate:

  - 20.000 PD for 80%
- My (Upper-Bound?) estimate:

  - 20.000 PD for 50%
  - 80.000 PD for 80% (don't forget, code might not be well testable)

The truth is probably somewhere in between.